# Correctly converting for-loops to parallel loops

Tags: r, loops, parallel-processing

I have this dataset over here (e.g. students wrote an exam many times over a period of years and either pass or failed - I am interested in studying the effect of the previous test on the next test):

```
   id = sample.int(10000, 100000, replace = TRUE)
res = c(1,0)
results = sample(res, 100000, replace = TRUE)
date_exam_taken = sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2020/01/01'), by="day"), 100000, replace = TRUE)


my_data = data.frame(id, results, date_exam_taken)
my_data <- my_data[order(my_data$id, my_data$date_exam_taken),]

my_data$general_id = 1:nrow(my_data)
my_data$exam_number = ave(my_data$general_id, my_data$id, FUN = seq_along)
my_data$general_id = NULL

     id results date_exam_taken exam_number
7992   1       1      2004-04-23           1
24837  1       0      2004-12-10           2
12331  1       1      2007-01-19           3
34396  1       0      2007-02-21           4
85250  1       0      2007-09-26           5
11254  1       1      2009-12-20           6
```

I wrote this standard FOR LOOP and everything seems to work fine:

```
my_list = list()

for (i in 1:length(unique(my_data$id)))
    
{ 
    {tryCatch({
        
        start_i = my_data[my_data$id == i,]
        
        pairs_i =  data.frame(first = head(start_i$results, -1), second = tail(start_i$results, -1))
        frame_i =  as.data.frame(table(pairs_i))
        frame_i$id = i
        print(frame_i)
        my_list[[i]] = frame_i
    }, error = function(e){})
    }}


 final_a = do.call(rbind.data.frame, my_list)
```

**Now, I am trying to "optimize" this loop by using "doParallel" libraries in R.**

Using this post ([How to transform a "for loop" in a "foreach" loop in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55506788/how-to-transform-a-for-loop-in-a-foreach-loop-in-r)) as a tutorial, I tried to convert my loop as follows:

```
# does this mean I should set makeCluster() to makeCluster(8)???
 > detectCores()
[1] 8

my_list = list()
max = length(unique(my_data$id))

library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(cl <- makeCluster(3))

# note: for some reason, this loop isn't printing?

test = foreach(i = 1:max, .combine = "rbind") %dopar% {

    {tryCatch({
        
        start_i = my_data[my_data$id == i,]
        
        pairs_i =  data.frame(first = head(start_i$results, -1), second = tail(start_i$results, -1))
        frame_i =  as.data.frame(table(pairs_i))
        frame_i$id = i
        print(frame_i)
        my_list[[i]] = frame_i
    }, error = function(e){})
    }}


 final_b = do.call(rbind.data.frame, test)
```

Based on this - I have the following questions:

- **Have I correctly used the "doParallel" functionalities as they are intended to be used?**
- **Is there yet a better way to do this?**
- **Note**: I am looking to run this code on a dataset with around 10 million unique ID's

Comment: (Disclaimer: I'm the author) You might find the JottR blog post 'Parallelize a For-Loop by Rewriting it as an Lapply Call ' (2019-01-11) useful <https://www.jottr.org/2019/01/11/parallelize-a-for-loop-by-rewriting-it-as-an-lapply-call/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way with the parallel code written as a function.
I split the data by id beforehand, instead of comparing each id with the current index `i`. This saves some time. It also saves time to extract the `results` vector only once.

I don't know why, I haven't found any errors in my parallel code but **the final data.frame is not equal to the sequential output `final_a`, it has more rows**.

This is system dependent but as you can see in the timings, the 6 cores run is the fastest.

```r
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)
#> Loading required package: foreach
#> Loading required package: iterators

parFun <- function(my_data, ncores) {
  split_data <- split(my_data, my_data$id)
  
  registerDoParallel(cl <- makeCluster(ncores))
  on.exit(stopCluster(cl))
  
  test <- foreach(i = seq_along(split_data)) %dopar% {
    start_i_results <- split_data[[i]]$results
    n <- length(start_i_results)
    if(n > 1L) {
      tryCatch({
        pairs_i <- data.frame(first = start_i_results[-n], 
                              second = start_i_results[-1L])
        frame_i <- as.data.frame(table(pairs_i))
        frame_i$id <- i
        frame_i
      }, error = function(e) {e})
    } else NULL
  }
  final_b <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, test)
  final_b
}

set.seed(2022)
id <- sample.int(10000, 100000, replace = TRUE)
res <- c(1,0)
results <- sample(res, 100000, replace = TRUE)
date_exam_taken <- sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2020/01/01'), by="day"), 100000, replace = TRUE)
my_data <- data.frame(id, results, date_exam_taken)

my_data <- my_data[order(my_data$id, my_data$date_exam_taken),]

my_data$general_id = 1:nrow(my_data)
my_data$exam_number = ave(my_data$general_id, my_data$id, FUN = seq_along)
my_data$general_id = NULL

t0 <- system.time({
  my_list = list()
  
  for (i in 1:length(unique(my_data$id)))
    
  { 
    {tryCatch({
      
      start_i = my_data[my_data$id == i,]
      
      pairs_i =  data.frame(first = head(start_i$results, -1), second = tail(start_i$results, -1))
      frame_i =  as.data.frame(table(pairs_i))
      frame_i$id = i
      # print(frame_i)
      my_list[[i]] = frame_i
    }, error = function(e){})
    }}
  final_a = do.call(rbind.data.frame, my_list)
})

ncores <- detectCores()

# run with 3 cores
t3 <- system.time(parFun(my_data, 3L))
# run with 6 cores and save the result in `res6`
t6 <- system.time(res6 <- parFun(my_data, ncores - 2L))
rbind(t0, t3, t6)[,1:3]
#>    user.self sys.self elapsed
#> t0     12.86     1.00   15.37
#> t3      3.50     0.22    8.37
#> t6      3.61     0.46    7.65

head(final_a, 10)
#>    first second Freq id
#> 1      0      0    2  1
#> 2      1      0    3  1
#> 3      0      1    4  1
#> 4      1      1    0  1
#> 5      0      0    5  2
#> 6      1      0    3  2
#> 7      0      1    2  2
#> 8      1      1    0  2
#> 9      0      0    0  3
#> 10     1      0    1  3
head(res6, 10)
#>    first second Freq id
#> 1      0      0    2  1
#> 2      1      0    3  1
#> 3      0      1    4  1
#> 4      1      1    0  1
#> 5      0      0    5  2
#> 6      1      0    3  2
#> 7      0      1    2  2
#> 8      1      1    0  2
#> 9      0      0    0  3
#> 10     1      0    1  3

str(final_a)
#> 'data.frame':    38945 obs. of  4 variables:
#>  $ first : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
#>  $ second: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 ...
#>  $ Freq  : int  2 3 4 0 5 3 2 0 0 1 ...
#>  $ id    : int  1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
str(res6)
#> 'data.frame':    38949 obs. of  4 variables:
#>  $ first : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
#>  $ second: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 ...
#>  $ Freq  : int  2 3 4 0 5 3 2 0 0 1 ...
#>  $ id    : int  1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

The following version seems much  faster.

```
parFun2 <- function(my_data, ncores) {
  registerDoParallel(cl <- makeCluster(ncores))
  on.exit(stopCluster(cl))
  
  results_list <- split(my_data$results, my_data$id)
  
  test <- foreach(i = seq_along(results_list)) %dopar% {
    start_i_results <- results_list[[i]]
    n <- length(start_i_results)
    if(n > 1L) {
      tbl <- table(first = start_i_results[-n], 
                   second = start_i_results[-1L])
      frame_i <- as.data.frame(tbl)
      frame_i$id <- i
      frame_i
    } else NULL
  }
  data.table::rbindlist(test)
}
```

Comment: @ Rui Barradas: Thank you so much for your answer! Suppose I have 10 million unique ID's in my dataset - will this code " split_data <- split(my_data, my_data$id)" that will split the data into individual chunks still be a good idea?

Comment: @stats_noob That's a though question. Maybe the answer is no, not anymore. Can you try it and give feedback on what happened?

Comment: @ Rui Barradas : Sure! I will try that!

Comment: @ Rui Barradas: Is it possible to add a print statement to your code? I have been trying to do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74759716/r-printing-individual-iterations-from-loops ... but so far I could not find a direct way to do this?

Comment: For near-live progress updates when running in parallel, but also relaying of "print statements", message and warnings, see <https://progressr.futureverse.org/#foreach-with-dofuture>

Comment: @ Rui Barradas: do you think "doSNOW" and "makeClusterPSOCK()" might be useful in this question? Or is it irrelevant given that we are using "doParallel" and "foreach"?

Comment: @ Henrik B: thank you for your reply! I will check it out!

Comment: @stats_noob No, I don't believe that doSNOW will be better than `foreach/dopar`.

Comment: Thank you! makeClusterPSOCK also wont be any better?

Comment: @ Rui Barradas: Did I correctly vectorize this function here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74792478/vectorize-functions-in-r I tried to take this question and vectorize my code - is it correct in your opinion ? thanks!